# PHP memory exhaused issue even if memory_limit is OK

Tags: php, memory-management

First of all I know that these questions regarding "memory_limit" error have been asking several times and most of the solutions given involve ini_set modifications but I don't think that is my case.

In fact I'm exactly receiving: 
[21-Apr-2013 22:21:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16000 bytes) in /home/xxx/public_html/www4/admincenter/clientes/102/slides/nuevo_slide.php on line 20

as you can see the total memory allowed size is really more than the size that the function was trying to allocate but I'm still receiving the same error :\
As far as I was able to see there's should be an issue with the imagecreatefromjpeg function (as pointed out by the error line: 20)

Here's my code:
By the way it works fine with img1 and not with img2:

- img1 = 139kb, 1000 x 300 px
- img2 = 648kb, 4000 x 3000 px

Both size are under the memory allowed.
I really appreciate your help on this.
Thanks!

```
<?php ini_set("memory_limit", "100M");  ?>
<?php require_once '/home/xxx/private_html/0a/configuration.php';?>
<?php require_once '/home/xxx/private_html/102/configuration.php';?>
<?php

    $titulo = ucwords($_POST['titulo']);
    $texto = utf8_encode($texto);

    $q = "INSERT INTO slides (`id`, `titulo`, `texto`, `fecha`) VALUES (NULL, '".$titulo."', '".$texto."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    $sql = mysql_query($q);
    $id = mysql_insert_id();

    for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++){
        if ($_FILES["foto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["foto"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg" ){
            if($_FILES["foto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["foto"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"){    
                $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"]);                   
            }       

            if ($i == 1){
                $max_upload_width = 902;
                $max_upload_height = 289;
                $remote_file = $sld .$id."_".$max_upload_width."x".$max_upload_height.".jpg";               
            }

            if ($i == 2){
                $max_upload_width = 166;
                $max_upload_height = 67;
                $remote_file = $sld .$id."_".$max_upload_width."x".$max_upload_height.".jpg";               
            }

            imagejpeg($image_source,$remote_file,100);
            chmod($remote_file,0755);

            // get width and height of original image
            list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
            if($image_width>$max_upload_width || $image_height >$max_upload_height){
                $proportions = $image_width/$image_height;
                if($image_width>$image_height){
                    $new_width = $max_upload_width;
                    $new_height = round($max_upload_width/$proportions);
                }else{
                    $new_height = $max_upload_height;
                    $new_width = round($max_upload_height*$proportions);
                }       

                $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($max_upload_width , $max_upload_height);
                $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);

                imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image_source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $max_upload_width, $max_upload_height, $image_width, $image_height);
                imagejpeg($new_image,$remote_file,100);
                imagedestroy($new_image);
            }   
            imagedestroy($image_source);
        }
    }

    header("Location: index.php?msg=350");
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: The first `$image_source` will be leaked each time `$image_width>$max_upload_width || $image_height >$max_upload_height`. Also, you're vulnerable to SQL injection; use prepared statements and PDO/MySQLi instead of the deprecated `mysql_` set of extensions.

Comment: Also, why do you have a nested `if` statement that checks the exact same thing as its container?

Comment: Also also, the JPEG-compressed size of a 4000 x 3000px image and the in-memory size of a 4000 x 3000px image are very different.

Comment: `Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16000 bytes)`... Memory has already been allocated for PHP itself, with its extensions, and for other variables assigned by your script: and PHP tries to allocate an __additional__ 16000 bytes that pushes it over the 52428800 threshold